# Can GoDaddy unlimited bandwidth hosting handle 8000 simultaneous users or should I purchase a dedicated server?

Tags: webserver, shared-hosting

I developed an online admission software for College Admission.

I have a Deluxe shared hosting in GoDaddy. As per them, I am getting **Unlimited** bandwidth for my domains.

The software will be hosted differently for each Colleges in their own domain name.

Suppose 4 College's admission is going on and at the same time about 2000 users/colleges(domain) are filling their forms. That means total 8000 users are active at the same time.

**My question is, can my hosting handle this or I have to purchase dedicated server to perform it. And how much bandwidth I need to make active about 6000-8000 users at-a-time ?**

For your information, I have tested my software in Google Pagespeed and the rating is 84. So I can tell it is not too slow.

**UPDATE**

I called GoDaddy Customer support. They cannot assure me about this (in fact, they never assure anything about shared hosting). As per them, my application may become slow due to the RAM I am getting now. That is only 512MB (In Ultimate Hosting plan, the RAM is only 1GB).

**FOUND SOMETHING**

Visit [here](https://in.godaddy.com/help/how-many-visitors-can-view-my-site-at-once-3206), and you will know about GoDaddy Shared Hosting.

Comment: You need to load test it.   There is no other way to figure out the performance capability of a web application.   I have my doubts as to whether a shared hosting plan could handle that load elegantly.   Even if it could, the custom coding in your web app may exhibit its own bottlenecks.  The only way you can know whether you are good to go is to run software against the site that simulates the peak load you are expecting.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thank you for the idea. I really need to test it.

Comment: You'll need to check how many concurrent connections  are allowed.

Comment: Any service offering "unlimited" anything should always be looked at with a jaundiced eye. They're trying to pull the wool over your eyes with this marketing coverup.

Comment: Instead of going for unlimited bandwidth go for stable hosting company. Godaddy can be used for a hobby site not for a business purpose. I will suggest you to go for digital ocean if you can setup the server. You will save your self  your customers slot of headache

Answer (score 3):

I've used GoDaddy's unlimited (and cheap) monthly plans, and a basic Wordpress site with more than about 3 users clicking around at the same time will give overload warnings (GoDaddy will email you if your server is using most of it's resources).

You can always view charts of the load on your server using the apps in your cPanel at GoDaddy. Also, you can do a free load test up to 25 users at [www.LoadImpact.com](http://www.loadimpact.com) and watch your GoDaddy shared server likely get totally overloaded and sluggish.

So having 6-8k users is definitely going to be far from any unlimited cheap plan that GoDaddy/HostGator and others may offer you. But the only way to be sure is to use scripting services that simulate load (like mentioned above) and go from there.

Comment: Hi Tony, I've tested at LoadImpact, but the hosting not getting slow/overloaded.

Comment: @Raj You may want to try a couple of load test script services like that. If 25 users doesn't slow things down at all, and you don't notice any movement in the charts for your load (from your cPanel), then somethings not right w/ the test. But I assure you that people aren't spending $1000+ a month at Amazon Web Services, Rackspace, etc for their heavy use websites because they just didn't hear about $9.99/mo hosting from HostGator. :) Those servers typically overload quickly. Best of luck!